# How to stack text over a banner? & Background image for the rest of the site

Tags: html, css

This is my first HTML page and I can't manage to stack text on a top banner, would prefer if you explain how and why it is like that, doing that for school but I wasn't in class when the teacher explained HTML.

Basically I just want to stack the anchor tags on top of the Banner image like some websites, then proceed to put a background image for the rest of the website. I think it is done with that.

PS my text goes after the image and not behind it or something like that.

```css
p {
   <background-image: src = "Background.jpg">
}
```

correct me if I'm wrong

**HTML**:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
            <title>Watched Anime List</title>
            <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "banner">
            <img class = "banner-image" src = "img/banner.jpg">
            <ul class = "nav">
                <div class = "logo">
                    <a href ='#'> My Anime List </a>
                </div>
                <li><a href = "#"> <b> Home </b> </a> </li>
                <li><a href = "#"> <b> Anime List </b> </a> </li>
                <li><a href = "#"> <b> Favourites </b> </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav {
    color: #ffffff;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

.nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.nav > li > a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000000;
}

.nav > li > a:hover {
    color: #ff0000;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.logo > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

.banner {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.banner > .banner-image {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to get the ul to overlap the img above it? Also, the div you have inside the ul is invalid - the only permitted direct descendant of a ul (or ol) is li.

Comment: I think i'm trying to get the ul to overlap the img yea, also what div inside the ul is invalid? i m new on html so i don't know much about it.

Comment: The `<div class = "logo">` that you have inside that ul can't be there, according to the HTML spec. Your browser will do it's best to work around that, when rendering the page, but you want to avoid invalid markup whenever possible. The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) is a good place to start, and it has links to the official HTML standards at the bottom of each element's article, for reference.

Comment: But then the Logo isn't on the same row as the others, how do i change that?

Comment: Change the div to an li.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that first bit of code? `<background-image: src = "Background.jpg">` is not in any way valid.

Answer (score 1):

Would not be better to use the image as the background of the banner?

Something like this ?

```css
.banner {
  background-color: #eee;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/600/300');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.my-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.my-menu div {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: white 1px solid;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.my-menu div:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="my-menu">

    <div>First button</div>
    <div>Second button</div>
    <div>third button</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set banner to float left as well as the content of the banner in order to stack them. Otherwise use z-index. Default is 0.

Comment: Where do i put z-index?
PS my text goes after the image and not behind it or something like that.
Tried on everything didn't work

Comment: z-index of -1 will work because it will allow you to have elements that are at z-index 0 to show up over it. What most often now i use though is that i set my element that i want on next of one another, rather than on top of, i set all of these elms to display inline and then the rest of my elms to block. the inline components then appear on the same line. again work with these display over floating, but if inline or inline-block isn't working, then do a float left to the rems you want stacked

Answer (score 0):

Don’t float if you don’t have to. use inline block on elements that you want on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you really need to use overlapping tags to accomplish what you're after. The `<ul>` element is a block level element, so setting the background image should work and produce the same effect.

Here's an example, https://jsfiddle.net/axbtpj40/, using this CSS:

```css
.banner
{
  border: solid;
}

.nav
{
  overflow: auto;
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1500x100) left center no-repeat;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav li
{
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav li a
{
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.nav li.logo a
{
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

The text you see to the far right, 1500x100, is part of the image generated by the Placeholder.com site, but it also serves to demonstrate how the background image fills the unordered list element.

If you go this route, you need to make sure that the background image is either relatively wide, can be blended into the background color of either the banner or the body, or is repeatable.